# Does a change in a query executed with sp_executesql cause recompilations?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan

I am experiencing a lot of re-compilations in my database. Most of the queries being executed are simple queries and all of them are being executed using the `sp_executesql` stored procedure.

Sometimes the query changes (not the parameters, but the query itself). I know this causes  SQL Server to invalidate the plan.

If I change this query:

```
exec sp_executesql 
        N'SELECT nome 
        from customer 
        where name = @name'
    ,N' @name varchar(50)'
    , @name=N'rafael';
```

to

```
exec sp_executesql 
        N'SELECT nome, address, phone 
        from customer 
        where name = @name'
    ,N' @name varchar(50)'
    , @name=N'rafael';
```

The plan will be invalidated.

Does this also cause a re-compilation?

Those queries are not the queries I am running, they are only examples.

**EDIT**

I am not using `#temp` tables. Bellow are 2 queries that are being recompiled:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 X, Y, Z 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Contains(VarcharMaxField, @Clause) 
    AND XXX IN (SELECT data FROM fn_ArrayTable(@Pub)) 
    AND YYY = 1 AND ZZZ < DateAdd(n, -10, GetDate()) 
ORDER BY A, B, C;

SELECT TOP 1000 A, B, C 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Contains(VarcharMaxField, @Clause) 
    AND (XXX IN (@Pub0,@Pub1)) 
    AND (AAA= 1) 
    AND (BBB< DateAdd(n, -10, GetDate())) 
ORDER BY A, B C;
```

I had to change the fields due to an internal company policy. The `fn_ArrayTable` is a function that returns a comma separated string as a table.

[image: Print]

Comment: Your EventSubClass column indicates that there was a schema change and that caused the recompile. This leads me to think you might be using # temp tables. Can you confirm this?

Comment: No, I am not using #temp tables.

Comment: Any possible changes in the underlying table schema at all? Would it be possible to post the code for the proc (anonamyzing object names)?

Comment: No one is changing the schema, thats I am sure. I just posted the code.

Comment: If you remove the `CONTAINS` predicate, does it still cause a recompile?

Comment: @JonSeigel Yes, it does.

Comment: I believe it is because of the variation in your queries. Every time a query changes (even just the whitespace) then it needs to be recompiled. I would recommend reading Conor Cunningham's post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2009/05/18/conor-vs-recompiles.aspx

Comment: @nic well, i have a lot of queries that look like the same using differents execution plans ...

Comment: @Nic also, this does not explain why the profiler shows me a "schema changed".

Answer (score 1):

It won't actually cause a recompilation, rather you have a completely new query and so it will have to be compiled for the first time.

If these sp_executesql statements are being called from within a stored procedure there might be some other cause for the recompile (such as a temp table or option).

I would recommend following the steps in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243586 to troubleshoot exactly what statement is causing your recompilations.

Comment: Those statements are not being called from within a stored procedure and I know what statemens are causing my recompilations but i have no ideia why since they are very very simple (but they use a fulltext search).

Comment: Do you know if the plan stays in cache between executions?

Comment: No, I dont and I have do idea how to check it. :)

Comment: Here's a basic look into items in the cache

`SELECT TOP 100
        ISNULL(DB_NAME(dbid), 'ResourceDB') ,
        objectid ,
        usecounts ,
        cacheobjtype ,
        objtype ,
        TEXT AS SQL
FROM    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans decp
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) dest
ORDER BY usecounts DESC;
`